# Modelica conditional printing (for debugging)

Tags: debugging, if-statement, modelica

In Modelica, is it possible to have an if-condition and a command in one line?
(Of course it is possible to write it in three lines, but I would prefer it in one line.)
Something like:

```
Boolean verbose;
...
if verbose then Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print("iteration steps " + String(iter), "printlog.txt");
```

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650920/use-asserts-for-debugging-modelica

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is wrong with the code you wrote? Only thing I find missing is the end if.

`if cond then print(str, file); end if;`

Comment: You are right, with `end if;` it works. I should have tried this myself. Now I only have to stop Dymola from messing up the code...