# use asserts for debugging Modelica

Tags: debugging, constants, assert, modelica

In Modelica, one could define a `protected final constant Boolean debug` and then use that in an assert statement to print out some values while debugging, similar to the code shown below (or [as seen on github](https://git.io/fNKRe)).

In the final version, debug would then be set to false. Would that slow down the simulation or does the assert get eliminated, because debug is a constant?

```
model debugexample
  parameter Real a;
  parameter Real b;
  Real sum;

protected 
  final constant Boolean debug = false "set to true while debugging";

equation 
  assert(not debug, "a=" + String(a), level=AssertionLevel.warning);
  sum = a+b;
end debugexample;
```

Comment: It is gone completely in the mof/dsmodel.c file if `debug=false`. Assertion code comes back to mod/dsmodel.c if `debug=true`. Tested on Dymola 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assert would be eliminated because `debug` is constant. If `debug` is a parameter however the assert might (depending on the tool) still only be called once rather than every timestep, because the `Boolean` input to assert is not changing.